# Gateway WebService Flexcube

Tags: web-services, weblogic-10.x, gateway

I try to use FLEXCUBE Gateway Webservice for that I use weblogic and deployed ear file of webservice. I depolyed them successfully; Hovewer, when  I send request with FCUBSCreateCustomerService I got this error : 
ECODE>GW-ROUT0003
            No data found for the service, operation and source combination

and this is my xml file that I send request

[image]

Is there any one have any idea about this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flexcube Webservice, deployment is not enough. You also need to do all the configuration to allow this web service to expose Flexcube functionalities to the outer world.

Answer (score 1):

There are some pending maintenance's that you need to do on Flexcube, most times its centered around the service(FCUBSCustomerService) and operation(CreateCustomer) and the Userid

Answer (score 0):

Check the userid FCATOP is valid user id for FCUBS. I have also faced GW-ROUT0003 for invalid user id.

Comment: Seems like a comment

Answer (score 0):

Function and Action needs to be mapped for each webservice. Screen ID in flexcube -> GWDEXFUN

Answer (score 0):

You need to following maintenance:- /n /br
1. Do source->module maintenance on function ID: CODUPLDM /n /br
1. Do Source->FunctionID->Service/method maintenance on function ID: GWDEXFUN /n /br

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain the service,operation and source combination in function_id **GWDETFUN** to overcome the issue **GW-ROUT0003**.For more information you can check the [Gateway Services Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E94300_01/html/GW/GWTOC.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to do the maintenance in flexcube for below data then try to test the req in soap ui.

If configuration is correct you can able to connect through webservices.
    FCUBSHEADERType header = new FCUBSHEADERType();
        UBSCOMPType ubsType = UBSCOMPType.fromValue("FCUBS");
        header.setUBSCOMP(ubsType);
        header.setSOURCE("FCAT");
        header.setMSGID(messageId);
        header.setCORRELID(messageId);
        header.setUSERID("ADMINUSER1");
//      header.setPASSWORD(soapPasswordService.encryptPassword(messageId));
        header.setBRANCH("000");
        header.setSERVICE("FCUBSAccService");

these are some header parameter that you can configure and send in header.
```